# How to update table based on the value of other table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I update a Table2 based on the values in Table1.  I want to update the Total field in Table2 with the values in Table1  Here is the structure of my table

**Table1**

```
Name1             Name2
Value1            value2
```

**Table2**

```
Type             Total
Name1            Value1
Name2            Value2
```

Comment: Sounds like you would benefit from reading up on `SQL`.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general something like that. Just be aware that the inner query can only return 1 column and one reccord aka 1 result

```
UPDATE table2 
SET total = (
         SELECT value2 
         FROM table1 WHERE name = value1
        ) 
WHERE table2.type = Name2
```

Comment: thanks Jester, but in the inner query when you say select value2.... i don't know ahead value2, it is dynamic numbers it could be 4 or 6 etc in this case how would i solve this?

Comment: on what does it depand witch value you are gonna have. Can you give some plastic examples like in example1 the tables would look like this and I would like to update table one like this bease of ?? And in example2 when tables looks like this (different) I would like to have table1 updateted like this because of ?? So I get an Idea on what your decision depands how the table gets updated

Comment: And also important from what or where you get the value you neeed to update from